# Bootstrap buttons not responsive in React

Tags: reactjs, button, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having problems getting a responsive bootstrap button in React. The button is designed the way I expected, but completely unresponsive. Any ideas?

```
{numUsers > 1 && this.props.phase === "Game Over" ? <button onClick
{this.props.deal} type="button" className="btn btn-
primary">Deal</button> : ""}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. If that solves your problem, google `Javascript operator precedence` for explanation.

```
{(numUsers > 1 && this.props.phase === "Game Over") ? <button onClick
{this.props.deal} type="button" className="btn btn-
primary">Deal</button> : ""}
```